# Copy entries from CSV file to Google App Engine Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, csv, google-cloud-datastore

I have one CSV file with approximately 100 rows of data. Something like this:

Individuals.csv:

```
description,key,name,lastname
aaaaa aaaaa,1,Aname,Alastname
bbbbb bbbbb,2,Bname,Blastname
...
...
```

Inside my datastore I have an Entity Individual which I need to populate with that data from `Individuals.csv`.

I saw a couple of solutions but it doesn't work for me. Maybe they changed something how it's done. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I am trying to do this this whole day.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Bulk upload](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata) if you want to automate things or you could use [Remote API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi) to do that kind of manually.

If you're not doing it that often and you just want to do it once then I think it's easier to do it using the Remote API and manually parse the data and write it, because using the bulk upload might take you a while to setup correctly the `bulkloader.yaml`, but in the end of the day is really up to you.

Comment: Absolutely agree, for just a 100 rows, just using the interactive shell will be the quickest.

Comment: Thanks. I checked that Remote API link but it's still not clear to me how to insert CSV data and from where to access that remote API link. Do I need to place CSV data inside my Google App Engine App or?